# Reading from transaction tables

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have 2 tables which need to get refreshed every one hour. One table is a truncate load and other one is an incremental load. Total process takes around 30 seconds to complete. There are couple of applications hitting these tables on a continuous basis. I can't have applications with blank data at any moment. Any idea what could be done so that operations on these table doesn't affect the output on UI (including truncate/load)? I am thinking of creating a MV on these tables, but any better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the `TRUNCATE` to a `DELETE` and make the whole process one transaction.  If the current process only takes 30 seconds the extra overhead of deleting and conventional inserts shouldn't be too bad.